How to add doctrine debug logs to production logs in case of an error on Symfony7
I am using this common Monolog configuration for my production environment:
when@prod:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
            nested:
                type: rotating_file
                max_files: 30
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug

Although it shows my inline debug level errors in case of an action level equal or higher than error, it does not shows the doctrine debug action level errors I need to debug the issue in my production environment.
How can I add doctrine debug level errors on the nested handler when a error level error occurs in the main fingers_crossed handler?
I am expecting the debug action level errors of doctrine handlers to show in my production error logs when an action level error occurs, but it does not.
